# Alert not showing(javafx)

Tags: java, javafx, alert

I am scanning an ID with OCR. These are given as key strokes so I check for the first 5 keys and if they are correct there are 85 more. 
This gives me the following code

```
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            switch(event.getCode()) {
                case SHIFT: break;
                default:
                    scanList.add(event.getText());
                    last5Keys.removeFirst();
                    last5Keys.add(event.getCode());
                    if(last5Keys.equals(IDcode)) {
                        scanList.clear();
                        inID=true;
                    }
            }
            if((inID)&&scanList.size()==85) {

                if(vornachgeb.contains(idScanned())) {

                    //do something
                }
                else {

                    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Person nicht gefunden. Als Gast hinzufügen?", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
                    alert.showAndWait();

                    if (alert.getResult() == ButtonType.YES) {
                        System.out.println("Test");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In the second if clause I am checking if the scanned ID is in another list. If not I want an alert to show. The if clause works fine but the alert is not showing. I even get 'Test' written out in the console.

Why is the alert not showing and even choosing 'Yes' for me?

Comment: Something you are not showing must be the problem. I just give a try with a quick [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the Alert pops up and waits for the user answer/click.

Comment: what could be missing? Is the part in the if claus (rn it states //do something) from importance? Otherwise I included everything from the setOnKeyPressed. my own function idScanned()?

Comment: Try to make a MCVE just for showing the alert without your functional code. And then debug your current code, set a breakpoint to the line `alert.showAndWait();` and have a look on the reason/the event which makes the popup disappear before seeing it.

Comment: I think I figured it out. The OCR Scanner adds an 'ENTER' at the end which for some reason doesnt trigger any functions in my program, but leads to the problem I described. Thanks Pagbo